# Adding of fields doesn't get added to the POST

Tags: jquery, laravel

Am trying to add an option for multiple colors inside a form. Problem is that even after adding a button that adds a new field below the first color field, the succeeding fields doesn't get saved in both of jQuery calls and a dd() on the PHP controller.

For reference

```
<form action="{{ route('item.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form"> @csrf
    // trimmed other fields
    <div class="wrapperColor">
        <label for="color">Color/s</label>
        <div class="row" style="padding: 1% 0;">
            <div class="col-9 form-group">
                <input type="text" name="color[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Black" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="add_field_button btn btn-md text-dark">Add More Colors</button>

    // trimmed other fields
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">SUBMIT</button>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        var wrapper = $(".wrapperColor");
        var add_button = $(".add_field_button");
        var x = 1; //initlal text box count

        $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();

            x++;

            var html = '';
            html += '<div class="row form-group" style="padding: 1% 0;">';

                html += '<div class="col-9">';
                    html += '<input type="text" name="color[]" class="form-control">';
                html += '</div>';

                html += '<div class="col-3">';
                    html += '<a href="#" class="remove_field"><i class="fas fa-times fa-lg" style="color: red;"></i></a>';
                html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';

            $(".wrapperColor").append(html);
        });

        $(".wrapperColor").on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').parent('div').remove();
            x--;
        });

        $("#form").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log($('#form').serializeArray()); // only gets the first field
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
```

Here's what I'm getting after submit is clicked.

[image: log]

Answer (score 0):

Tried moving the form tags from within inside the modal-header to inside the modal-dialog and it weirdly worked. Why/How did that happen?